# Determine all interpretations which satisfy $\varphi_n :=\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n}(X_i \vee \neg Y_i)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Taken from an old exam:

> Determine all interpretations which satisfy $\varphi_n
> :=\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n}(X_i \vee \neg Y_i)$ and where also you only need
>   to change the interpretation of one logical variable so that
>   $\varphi_n$ is no longer satisfied. Reason your choice.

So an interpretation satisfies a propositional formula if that formula is true for specific inputs.

Let's say we set $n=4:$

$$(X_1 \vee \neg Y_1) \wedge (X_2 \vee \neg Y_2) \wedge (X_3  \vee \neg Y_3) \wedge (X_4 \vee \neg Y_4)$$

If we set $X_i=0$ and $Y_i=0$, then $\varphi_n$ will be true. So the interpretation for this is

$I(X_i) = I(Y_i)=0$ this satisfies $\varphi_n$ and if you change $I(Y_i)$ to $1$, then $\varphi_n$ is no longer satisfied.

I don't think there is another interpretation because if $I(X_i)=1$, it doesn't matter what $I(Y_i)$ is because they are connected with an OR. So in that case the interpretation satisfies $\varphi_n$ as well BUT it doesn't satisfy "and where also you only need

> to change the interpretation of one logical variable so that
>   $\varphi_n$ is no longer satisfied"

Is it alright like that or how would you do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure you can make $\varphi_n$ false by just changing one logical variable, you must make sure there is an $i$ for which you can either change $X_i$ or $Y_i$ to make it so $X_i \vee \neg Y_i$ is no longer satisfied. This means either $I(X_i)=0$ and $I(Y_i)=0$ or $I(X_i)=1$ and $I(Y_i)=1$. In the former case you can switch $Y_i$, in the latter $X_i$.

Also you of course need to make sure that $\varphi_n$ is satisfied by making sure each $X_i \vee \neg Y_i$ is satisfied, so you need $I(X_i)=1$ or $I(Y_i)=0$.

So the valid interpretations $I$ satisfy the following:

$\exists i.I(X_i)=I(Y_i)\wedge \forall i.(I(X_i)=1\vee I(Y_i)=0)$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "in the former case you can switch $Y_i$, in the latter $X_i$" and in last line the $\exists$ and $\forall$ why they are there?

Comment: $\exists$ = "there is/there exists" and $\forall$ = "for all". Sorry, I assumed you were familiar with those. Just an English equivalent would be: "There is some $i$ for which $I(X_i)=I(Y_i)$ and further for all $i$ we have $I(X_i)=1\vee I(Y_i)=0$

Comment: Great thanks so much :)